# Unable to click on a link with CasperJS

Tags: javascript, testing, ssl, phantomjs, casperjs

I am trying to click a link with CasperJS, but am receiving this odd error: `[warning] [phantom] Loading resource failed with status=fail (HTTP 200): http://njit.edu/`. Here is my code:

```
// Creating a casper module instance
var casper = require('casper').create({
  verbose: true,
  logLevel: "debug"
});

var config = {
  url: 'http://telluswho2.herokuapp.com/',
};

casper.start(config.url);

casper.then(function() {
  console.log(this.getCurrentUrl());
  this.click('a.btn-lg:nth-child(3)');
  console.log(this.getTitle());
});

casper.run(function() {
  console.log(this.getTitle());
  this.exit();
});
```

Here are the solutions I have tried:

- `casperjs njit.js`
- `casperjs njit.js --ssl-protocol=any`
- `casperjs njit.js --ssl-protocol=tlsv1`
- `casperjs njit.js --ignore-ssl-errors=yes`
- `casperjs njit.js --ignore-ssl-errors=true`
- `casperjs njit.js --ignore-ssl-errors=false`
- `casperjs --ssl-protocol=any njit.js`
- `casperjs --ssl-protocol=tlsv1 njit.js`
- `casperjs --ignore-ssl=yes njit.js`

All of these possible solutions result in the same error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my quick testing, I believe the button redirects to http://njit.edu/ instead of http://www.njit.edu/ and that's why you are receiving that error.

Then there is an automatic from http://njit.edu/ to http://www.njit.edu/, but PhantomJS is not able to perform this redirect for some reason.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion how PhantomJS can be convinced to open the page/correctly redirect? With a quick testing SlimerJS does this without a problem.

Comment: You can use onResourceReceived, here's an example I found: [phantomjs redirect handling](https://gist.github.com/amenzhinsky/5245915)